# Loop on Array<keyof interface>

Tags: typescript

I have an object called Item, I have defined an interface that contains its fields, and an array of fields that can be changed and defined.
When the user wants to update the item, he sends a POST request with the updated item, and I go through the array and update the fields according to the user's data.
The problem is that Typescript throws an error:
Type 'string | number 'is not assignable to type' never '.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts (2322)

I would appreciate any help on the subject

```
interface Item {
    id?: number;
    title?: string;
    price?: number;
}

const requiredItemFields: Array<keyof Item> = [
    "title",
    "price",
]

app.post('/update-item', (req, res) => {
    const existItem: Item = req.body.item;
    const newItem: Item = {};
    for (let filed of requiredItemFields) {
        if (existItem.hasOwnProperty(filed)) {
            newItem[filed] = existItem[filed]; << ERROR
        }
    }
})
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHLAAmA-AFzIgCuGARtANz6FjBgA2EFyAzmFFABzZoWQAHQUh416TXAF9cuBAHsQ-ZAgAWcEEIhw6XdBAwAxYBA7FelAIJQocAJ4AeANYQXqmGkwAfMgAvMgA2iwEAERsnBBRADSRyFGSwEiJuAC6ynDi4gB04qr8ABQA5AD01OLEcJAAtOxm5QnIpVAQAI5tnbwAlCFBeGJqGmDIEAAewPymGJTzIcidXQV0qsQuBc0YooRjmiAQAO7zi5jL2Ar7BDCqUO1cEzDAXMTIvlq6%20obGEPNLNZbIMRmJCMA-KVprMwPMCrpeAB5E4gAAKUFU4mgYBcpVe736oOS4MIxzOmDCBIgxCyyxhc0p1Npt3BSjESgU-SAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is typescript is not as smart as you think.

When you do :

```
newItem[filed] = existItem[filed];
```

typescript doesn't assume that `newItem[filed]` will be of the same type as `existItem[filed]`.

To it, `existItem[filed]` could be of any type behind Item keys.

As an validation of what I'm saying, we can see that the following is working :

```
newItem[filed as 'id'] = existItem[filed as 'id'];
```

---

What solution do you have ?

Force typescript to accept the affectation "I know what I'm doing, theses two values are of the same type".

```
newItem[filed] = existItem[filed] as any;
```

or

```
// @ts-ignore
newItem[filed] = existItem[filed];
```