# Is there any way in typescript to say "and any others"

Tags: typescript

Consider defining variable type in typescript:

```
userData: {id: number, name: string};
```

Is there any way to also allow any other keys with any types, so that they would not be validated?
Something like:

```
userData: {id: number, name: string, ...any};
```

Or maybe using modern type transformation operators?

Appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[key: string]`:

```
userData: {
  id: number
  name: string
  [key: string]: any;
};
```

@GrégoryNEUT is right, `any` is not recommended. `unknown` is a good way, also unions are possible, like `string | number`. `key` might also be typed as e.g. `number`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @pzaenger correct answer, I will add that this is a bad behavior to use `any` to specify something.

`any` must be used only in very specific case when you want to force typescript to accept something that is true like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950951/loop-on-arraykeyof-interface/62951228#62951228)

You should rather use `unknown` that will force the user to check the additional data before using it

```
userData: {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  [key: string]: unknown;
};
```